# First-order model checking is not fixed parameter tractable on general graphs

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, first-order-logic, model-checking, parameterized-complexity

I read that the problem of first-order model checking is believed to be not fixed parameter tractable on general graphs.

Why is this the case? Would be happy about some reference

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fixed $k$, existence of a $k$-clique can be represented as a first order model formula: $\exists u_1 \dots u_k, (\bigwedge_{i < j} u_i \neq u_j ) \land (\bigwedge_{i < j} (u_i,u_j) \in E)$.

Because $k$-CLIQUE problem is $\mathrm{W}[1]$-hard, if the first-order model checking problem is $\mathrm{FPT}$ then $\mathrm{W}[1] = \mathrm{FPT}$, contradicting the popular belief that states otherwise.

Of course, such a statement cannot be proved without hypotheses because it implies $\mathrm{P} \neq \mathrm{NP}$.